# LTspice model showing wrong output voltage for op-amp (MP118 - Apex)

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, error

I attached my LTspice mode. The amplifier I'm using was downloaded from Apex microtechnology website for MP118. I made necessary connection as per the circuit diagrams I attached. But after running, I expect to see a -180 degree phase shifted sine wave with same frequency as input and the amplitude increase to 100 Vp-p because I set my gain to be 100 using the input and feedback resistor.

Is there any problem with my connections? But I'm getting 105 V straight line instead of a sine wave. Except the diodes in "my circuit" diagram everything else has been added. The spice model for MP118 can be found at "https://www.apexanalog.com/products/mp118.html".

Can anyone guide what mistake I did? Please note that I'm not from electrical background and this the first time I'm using LTspice.

[image: LT Spice model]

[image: My Circuit diagram]

[image: Typical connection-MP118]

Comment: There's also an [evaluation kit](https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/products/ek57u.pdf) and an applications note. High power / high voltage electronics does have different requirements from commonly used op-amps, but this module looks like it is designed to handle the kind of high voltage you're using in your model, I think... I don't see what's causing the problem...

Comment: Hi, yes physically I'm using that evaluation kit. But I would like to simulate different conditions to see the voltage output and the power dissipation in the amplifier.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

You haven't connected the non-inverting input of the op-amp to ground. You've only drawn the wire near the pointy end of the ground symbol, not attached it to the "pin" of the ground symbol. An electrical connection to the symbol is only made if you connect to the pin.

The pin is the little square shown on the symbol when you first place it (that goes away once you've connected a wire to it):
[image]

If you attach two wires to a ground symbol from the left and right, it will look like this:

[image]

Note: drawing the ground connection as above is not recommended. It would be better to extend a wire segment one or two squares downward and connect the ground symbol there so that it will appear clearly in the drawing.

Comment: Note that it's good practice to be a bit more obvious with your ground connections.  Just because the simulator will let you use a hard-to-read schematic doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: I just gave someone else here some tips on drawing schematics in LTspice a week or so ago and this was one of the things I mentioned. I cringe every time I see the ground on a horizontal wire like in that last image.

Comment: @GodJihyo, it's not meant to be an example of good drawing practice, just showing how an actually connected wire would be different from what is in OP's post.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh I wasn’t meaning you, I understood that was an example. I meant when people do it that way in the schematics they post. I see that quite a bit.

Comment: Hi. @ThePhoton Thanks and that's a good catch. I changed the connection but still the problem exists. I don't see the sine wave at the output instead i just see a straight line. I gave .6 vp-p at input and gave 40V for +DC supply and -40V for -DC supply. But if i measure the voltage after  Rf, i only see a straight line at 39.4 V. My gain is 100.

Comment: @Yaser, without seeing the whole circuit in the new form, I can't say. But a fixed output at just below VSP sounds like you still have a biasing problem. Check the DC value at all the other nodes and see if they have the voltage you expect.